# SQL displaying data from one table based on id from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new at SQL I a need help in creating one.

I have 2 tables:

**table 1:**

[image: table 1]

**table2:**

[image: table2]

And now I want first name and last name for all friends of one user example of user John Doe based on id from user and friend user id from table friends?

Comment: Most people prefer text rather than images, please Tag your database

Comment: is it mysql or t-sql ?

Comment: as @BHouse says, please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: mysql, the solution from Ezequiel López Petrucci worked

Comment: Inconsistent spelling of "friends" in the question and "firends" for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do 2 joins, one to get each friend's ID and another to retrieve that friend's name.

```
SELECT
    U.ID,
    U.first_name,
    U.last_name,
    N.first_name FriendFirstName,
    N.last_name FriendLastName
FROM
    [user] U
    LEFT JOIN firends F ON U.ID = F.user_id
    LEFT JOIN [user] N ON F.friend_id = N.id
```

Using a `LEFT JOIN` will make you see people with no friends (sniff).

If you want to see a particular user:

```
SELECT
    U.ID,
    U.first_name,
    U.last_name,
    N.first_name FriendFirstName,
    N.last_name FriendLastName
FROM
    [user] U
    LEFT JOIN firends F ON U.ID = F.user_id
    LEFT JOIN [user] N ON F.friend_id = N.id
WHERE
    U.ID = 1948 -- Supplied ID
```

Comment: I see you spotted the table was called 'firends'

Answer (score 1):

Do the self `join`s

```
select f.first_name, u.first_name as friend_name 
from user u 
join (
       select u.first_name, f.friend_id 
       from friend f
       join user u on u.id = f.user_id
) f on f.friend_id = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple inner join will do

```
Select First_name,Last_name 
from user inner join friends on user.id = friends.user_id
where friends.id = 1
```

Or you can replace with `friends.user_id = 1` if you would like to look at `user_id` column

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm getting it wrong, but this is my suggeston:

```
    SELECT 
            u1.first_name,
            u1.last_name,
            u2.first_name AS FriendFirstName,
            u2.last_name AS FriendLastName,                
    FROM user AS u1
    INNER JOIN friends AS f
        ON t1.id = f.user_id
    INNER JOIN user AS u2
        ON f.friend_id = u2.id
```